# How to add a background image into blender?

Tags: 3d-view, image

I'm new to blender and im trying to put an image into blender. These are the steps I'm taking:

1. <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd> to add an image in
2. <kbd>N</kbd> to bring the properties panel
3. enable background image
4. than chose the image I want

is there a step I'm missing?
I've seen multiple questions on this but I just can't work them out
I am in in orthographic view but the image doesn't show up.
I want to use it so that I can make a rig and compare it

Comment: That's what you do to add a background image, which is only visible in the view port, in orthographic view (axis aligned).

Comment: What are you trying to do with the image once you get it into blender?  (e.g. edit it, apply it as a texture, trace over it)

Comment: @Polosson you could of edited it and fixed it, instead of just commenting on what he did wrong.

Comment: @noob probably you didn't switch to orthographic mode (numpad 5)

Comment: Do you want your final render to appear in front of a background image? In this case, you can use the compositor.

Comment: Make sure you are also in a view aligned to an axis (e.g. numpad 1)